How to increase the mesh size in NDsolve
I am trying to increase the domain over which I solve a differential equation with NDsolve. However, when I tried doing this I started getting very poor results. After some googling I learned that this is because the total number of mesh cells stay the same over a larger domain. Is there a way for me to increase this total number without creating my own mesh for NDsovle?

You can do that though a Method option but the exact option dependents on whether the DE is stationary or time dependent:
(* stationary *)
Method -> {"FiniteElement", 
  "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> XXXX}}

(* transient *)
Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> {"MethodOfLines", 
    "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", 
      "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> XXXX}}}}

You can find example on the NDSolve ref page under the Options then Methods section. You could get a better answer if your code had included the actual example.
